# Remotely accessing cassandra running on local loopback IP/port 127.0.0.1

Tags: interface

I have been using ccm for some time and it's pretty awesome tool to test out admin stuff. Now, I really want to test modeling data by trying to access ccm running cassandra using Thrift based pycassaShell client from remote hosts (not locally). My setup is like this:

Lets say, private IP of this machine is: 10.11.12.13 (Just an example)

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:67392708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:67392708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:7398829042 (6.8 GiB)  TX bytes:7398829042 (6.8 GiB)

lo:1  Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1

lo:2  Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.3  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1

lo:3  Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.4  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
```

and 127.0.0.1 (node1), 127.0.0.2 (node2), 127.0.0.3 (node3), 127.0.0.4 (node4)

```
$ ccm status
  node1: UP  
  node3: UP
  node2: UP
  node4: UP
```

How to connect to any of the instance from non-local hosts? When I do:
pycassaShell --host 10.11.12.13 --port 9160, it throws an exception,

thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to 10.11.12.13:9160

Is there a way to make it work?

#### References

In case you're unfamiliar,[CCM, or Cassandra Cluster Manager](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) is a script for managing instances of Cassandra nodes.

*excerpt*

> A script/library to create, launch and remove a Apache Cassandra cluster on
>   localhost.
>
> The goal of ccm and ccmlib is to make is easy to create, manage and destroy a
>   small cluster on a local box. It is meant for testing of a Cassandra cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish a tunnel with ssh to make it appear that pycassaShell is connecting from the server running Cassandra.

On the remote host, establish a SSH tunnel with this -
`ssh -N -L 9160:127.0.0.1:9160 10.11.12.13`

Then on the remote host, run `pycassaShell --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9160`

Alternatively, you could setup ccm to listen on a non-localhost port.